# If I initialise an ICollection as an Observable collection, why can’t I use observable collections methods?

Tags: c#, .net, observablecollection

I have an `ICollection` that I want to initialize as an observable collection.

```
ICollection<Thing> things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();
```

And then on that observable collection I’d like to call functions like `.Move` but I get errors. Why is this? Is things not actually an observable collection?

Comment: How are you calling it and which "errors" are you getting? Please [edit] your question to add those details

Comment: What do you mean you are calling `.Move`? There is no `Move` method on `ICollection<T>`. Please refine your question, preferably demonstrate the problem with a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also explain the type of error you are getting; is this a compile error? If so, please post the compile error message. Is this a runtime exception? If so, please post the exception details, which include the exception message, the exception type and the stack trace (and if applicable details of any inner exception).

Comment: That's how interfaces work. You need to use one that supports the functionality you need to be using.

Comment: I figured because observable collection derives from Collection should be able to use the observable collection .Move method, does it stay an icollection even though I set it to be an observable collection?

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring that the variable `things` is of the interface type `ICollection<Thing>`, and the reason you are able to initialise it as an `ObservableCollection<Thing>` is because the `ObservableCollection<T>` class **inherits** the `ICollection<T>` interface.

However, by declaring it this way, you will only have access to the members defined by the `ICollection<T>` interface, meaning any `ObservableCollection`-specific members will be inaccessible.

To change this, either declare `things` like so:

```
ObservableCollection<Thing> things = new ObservableCollection<Thing>();
```

or use type-casting:

```
var myObservableCollection = (ObservableCollection<Thing>)things;
```

Comment: Thank you for your response it was helpful. Could you explain why ObservableCollection members aren’t accessible?

Comment: @squareroot1764 For all intents and purposes, `things` is an `ICollection<Thing>` and therefore only has access to the members defined by that interface. Think of it like this, you have a variable declared with the interface `IHasTwoWheels` and initialise it with the concrete class `Car`. This is allowed because a `Car` typically has 4 wheels, however, you could also assign another class `Bicycle` to the same variable and have it work the same, because it also typically has 2 wheels. This goes more in-depth: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/interfaces